# Extract accounts without transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this table

Table1

> AccountID   TrackNumber   TransactionDate
>   MNL001          10001        
>              
>    20151101
>  MNL002     
>    10002             
>          20151102
>   MNL003          10003        
>              
>    20151103
>  MNL004     
>    10004             
>          20151102
>   MNL005          10005        
>              
>    20151101
>  MNL006     
>    10006             
>          20151101
>   MNL007          10007    
>              
>        20151103
>  MNL008     
>    10008             
>          20151102
>   MNL009       10009    
>              
>        20151101
>  MNL010     
>    10010          
>           20151103

and I want to get those AccountID who's don't have transaction.

output should be:

> TransationDate     AccountID 
>   20151101            
>    MNL002
>  20151101     
>          MNL003
>   20151101            
>    MNL004
>  20151101     
>          MNL007
>   20151101            
>    MNL008
>  20151101    
>           MNL010
>   20151102            
>    MNL001
>  20151102     
>          MNL003
>   20151102            
>    MNL005
>  20151102     
>          MNL006
>   20151102            
>    MNL007
>  20151102     
>          MNL009
>   20151102            
>    MNL010
>  20151103    
>           MNL001
>   20151103            
>    MNL002
>  20151103     
>          MNL004
>   20151103            
>    MNL005
>  20151103     
>          MNL006
>   20151103            
>    MNL008
>  20151103     
>          MNL009

Please help me to make this query in MS SQL 2008.

thanks

this my analysis

[image]

the problem is i don't know how to do this in query.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.  Can you clean it up a bit?

Comment: May you have 2 tables, Accounts and Transactions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CROSS APPLY`, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.TransationDate, B.AccountID
FROM Your_Table A
CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT AccountID FROM Your_Table WHERE TransationDate <> A.TransationDate
      ) AS B
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions.
One solution could be :

```
Select t.TransactionDate, t.AccountID
From table1 t
Where not exists 
      (select * 
       from table1 t2 
       where 
       t2.AccountID = t1.AccountID
       and t1.TransactionDate =  t2.TransactionDate
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `cross join` between distinct dates and accounts and search for non existing values in table with `left join`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      AccountID VARCHAR(10) ,
      TrackNumber VARCHAR(10) ,
      TransactionDate DATE
    )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'MNL001', '10001', '20151101' ),
        ( 'MNL002', '10002', '20151102' ),
        ( 'MNL003', '10003', '20151103' ),
        ( 'MNL004', '10004', '20151102' ),
        ( 'MNL005', '10005', '20151101' ),
        ( 'MNL006', '10006', '20151101' ),
        ( 'MNL007', '10007', '20151103' ),
        ( 'MNL008', '10008', '20151102' ),
        ( 'MNL009', '10009', '20151101' ),
        ( 'MNL010', '10010', '20151103' )

;WITH distinctAccounts AS(SELECT DISTINCT AccountID FROM @t),
      distinctDates AS(SELECT DISTINCT TransactionDate FROM @t)

SELECT dd.TransactionDate, da.AccountID 
FROM distinctAccounts da
CROSS JOIN distinctDates dd
LEFT JOIN @t t ON t.AccountID = da.AccountID AND t.TransactionDate = dd.TransactionDate
WHERE t.AccountID IS NULL
ORDER BY dd.TransactionDate, da.AccountID
```

Output:

```
TransactionDate AccountID
2015-11-01      MNL002
2015-11-01      MNL003
2015-11-01      MNL004
2015-11-01      MNL007
2015-11-01      MNL008
2015-11-01      MNL010
2015-11-02      MNL001
2015-11-02      MNL003
2015-11-02      MNL005
2015-11-02      MNL006
2015-11-02      MNL007
2015-11-02      MNL009
2015-11-02      MNL010
2015-11-03      MNL001
2015-11-03      MNL002
2015-11-03      MNL004
2015-11-03      MNL005
2015-11-03      MNL006
2015-11-03      MNL008
2015-11-03      MNL009
```